# boost::filesystem::exists() fails when specifying relative path from a file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

Suppose I have the following function defined and used to check whether a required file is available based on the path provided to it.

```
bool check_my_file_exists( const std::wstring& my_root_file ) 
{
    const std::wstring file_path = L"..\\..\\require_file.txt";
    const std::wstring relative_path_to_required_file = my_root_file + L"\\" + file_path;
    
    if ( !boost::filesystem::exists( relative_path_to_required_file ))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Suppose **D:\my_file\require_file.txt** exists and,
when calling this function with following an absolute path to file as argument, it fails always

```
check_my_file_exists( L"D:\\my_files\\this_folder\\that_folder\\root.file" ); // return false
```

but when specifying absolute path to parent folder of root file as argument this works as expected,

```
check_my_file_exists( L"D:\\my_files\\this_folder\\that_folder" ); // return true
```

It is also possible to open the required_file.txt when using D:\my_files\this_folder\that_folder\root.file....\required_file.txt in explorer.

Environment:

- Boost : 1.69
- Visual Studio 2017
- Windows 10, 2004

I was confused about whether it was some boost implementation issue or expected behavior.

Comment: Check your working directory and access

Comment: You cannot append `..` to a normal file name, only to a directory.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes, it makes sense. But such a case is working if it tried in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Yes, in Windows Explorer you can do this. Now what?

Comment: As you said the relative path should be from a working directory, not a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `boost::filesystem::exists()` function here.

According to your example `require_file.txt` exists in `"D:\\my_files\\this_folder\\that_folder\\..\\..\\require_file.txt"` where in terms of absolute path it is `"D:\\my_files\\require_file.txt"`, please keep this actual location in mind for further explanation.

```
if ( !boost::filesystem::exists( "D:\\my_files\\this_folder\\that_folder\\root.file\\..\\..\\require_file.txt"))
{
    return false;
}
```

So the constructed relative path is `"D:\\my_files\\this_folder\\that_folder\\root.file\\..\\..\\require_file.txt"` in terms of absolute path it is `"D:\\my_files\\this_folder\\require_file.txt"`. So you are checking in wrong path, that's why `exists()` function always returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Like I commented, you need to check your working directory and access. Relative paths will be interpreted relative to the "current working directory".

> You can transform an absolute path to a relative one e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#op-relative or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/relative

Next up, use forward slashes or properly escape your backslashes:

```
const std::wstring file_path = L"..\\..\\require_file.txt";
check_my_file_exists( L"D:\\my_files\\this_folder\\that_folder" ); // return true
```

If you enable warnings the compiler should tell you about invalid escape sequences

Comment: Thanks for the replay, corrected the backslashes issue. But I was a little confused about the access issue, if it was the case of current working directory access then both statements should fail right?